# Fetch only a single tag with JGit

Tags: git, jgit

On the git console, I can do the following to only fetch a single tag from a remote repository (remote not added):

```
git fetch -n git@github.company.com:organization/repo.git tag mytag
```

I wanted to try the same with JGit, but I cannot solve it.

```java
fetcher.remote = remoteName   //  (in this case remote is already added)
fetcher.setRefSpecs("${opts.mytagname}")
fetcher.setTagOpt(TagOpt.NO_TAGS)
fetcher.call()
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fetch a specific tag, you need to provide a refspec that explicitly asks for this tag. Fetching from a remote that is not configured is also possible with JGit. The `FetchCommand::setRemote` method accepts either the name of a known (i.e. configured) remote, like `origin`, or the full URL to a remote repository.

Both is illustrated in the following test:

```java
public class FetchTagTest {

  @Rule
  public final TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
  private Git remote;
  private Git local;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    File remoteDirectory = tempFolder.newFolder( "remote" );
    File localDirectory = tempFolder.newFolder( "local" );
    remote = Git.init().setDirectory( remoteDirectory ).call();
    local = Git.cloneRepository().setURI( remoteDirectory.getCanonicalPath() ).setDirectory( localDirectory ).call();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    local.getRepository().close();
    remote.getRepository().close();
  }

  @Test
  public void testFetchTag() throws Exception {
    remote.commit().setMessage( "tag me!" ).call();
    Ref remoteTag = remote.tag().setName( "tag" ).call();

    local.fetch()
        .setRemote( remote.getRepository().getDirectory().getCanonicalPath() )
        .setRefSpecs( new RefSpec( "refs/tags/tag:refs/tags/tag" ) )
        .call();

    List<Ref> localTags = local.tagList().call();
    assertEquals( 1, localTags.size() );
    assertEquals( remoteTag.getName(), localTags.get( 0 ).getName() );
    assertEquals( remoteTag.getObjectId(), localTags.get( 0 ).getObjectId() );
  }
}
```

Comment: oh my...here comes the silly part. I was using it in Groovy and did not recognise, that setRefSpecs() requires a RefSpec Object. I was just passing the String. Thanks. that helped a lot!

Comment: Glad you found it. Out of curiosity: does Groovy allow to automatically convert a Refspec into a string - or was it your fault to ignore the Groovy compiler?

Comment: at least IntelliJ did not give an error. So I guess some implicit casting was done without problems.